# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error', what(): cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, maxlength

I solved [416. Partition Equal Subset](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/) Sum problem as :

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto num : nums) sum += num;  // get sum
    
    if(sum%2 == 1) return false;  // not possible case - in odd sum
    

    sum /= 2;  // first halve the sum
    vector<bool> table(sum+1, false);  // create 1-d bool array, initialize false
    table[0] = true;  // mark starting true
    for(auto num : nums)  // for each num
    {
        for(int i=sum; i>=num; i--)  // from sum till it is greater than or num
        {
            table[i] = table[i] or table[i-num];  // Or with including this num or not
        }
    }
    return table[sum];
```

And I found similar problem [494. Target Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/), so I tried to solve by this same concept :

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto num : nums) sum += num;  // get sum        

    if(sum < target or (sum + target)%2 == 1) return 0;  // not possible case - sum < target or newSum is odd
    
    int newSum = (sum + target)/2;
    vector<int> table(newSum+1, 0);
    table[0] = 1;
    
    for(auto num : nums)
    {
        for(int i = newSum; i>=num; i--)
        {
            table[i] = table[i] + table[i-num];
        }
    }
    return table[newSum];
```

But, there is Runtime Error :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()
```

I Googled this issue to resolve it but was unable to find any easy solution that can help to understand me. Can you please help me to understand and resolve this issue?

Comment: This code throwing error for `
[100]
-200` test case.

Comment: We can't guess what `target` is. Is it a char array?

Comment: @273K , You are given an integer array nums and an integer target.

Comment: Please show a [mre], at a guess `newSum + 1` is a negative number

Comment: Usually we do not go to links. But I tried this time and got 404 Not found. Maybe a signing up is required. You should post an [mcve].

Comment: @AlanBirtles , noted. It works.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan [Birtles' commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836544/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdlength-error-what-cann?noredirect=1#comment128650508_72836544) above:

int tartget could be a negative number too, so `newSum`

```
int newSum = (sum + target)/2;  // can be negative number
vector<int> table(newSum+1, 0);  // so you can not assigne negative size of a `vector` here.
```

**Solution :** take absolute value `newSum` before assigning it to `vector` to make sure, size of vector is positive only, not negative.

```
int newSum = abs((sum + target)/2);  // take abs 
vector<int> table(newSum+1, 0);  // to make sure, size of vector is positive only, not negative.
```